# Cómo filtrar marcadores y datos mostrados y devueltos

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y necesito leer una tabla MysqSQL que contiene datos de inmuebles. La estructura básica es la que se muestra en la tabla inclída en el fichero app.php Buscando ejemplos, he encontrado uno que me sirve; lee la tabla, muestra los marcadores y los datos en una tabla bajo el mapa. Hasta aquí bien, pero necesitaría que, una vez recuperados los datos de la tabla y pintados los marcadores y la tabla con los datos, poder añadir filtros al mapa, es decir: si selecciono como filtro el país, que aparezcan solamente los marcadores que correspondan con el valor y también se actualice la tabla. Si tras país, quiero filtrar por dirección, que aparezcan actualizados nuevamente. Mása adelante añadiré un filtro para distancias o radios, y que pudiera ser tipo arrastrar o radio. Los ficheros utilizados son:
conexion.php

```
<?php 
//Nos conectamos a la Base de Datos MySQL
$con = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario", "pass", "db");
//Verificamos la conexión a la Base de Datos MySQL 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Error al Conectar a la base de Datos: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

info_marcadores.php

```
<?php
  // Agregamos el nombre y dirección a la ventana de información de cada //marcador, puedes agregar la información que desees, nosotros agregaremos //'nombre' y 'direccion' 
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
['<div class="info_content">' + '<h3><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></h3>' + '<p><?php echo $row['direccion']; ?></p>' + '</div>'], 
<?php }}
?>
```

marcadores.php

```
<?php
// Archivo de Conexión a la Base de Datos 
include('conexion.php');
// Listamos las direcciones con todos sus datos (lat, lng, dirección, etc.)
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM google_maps_php_mysql");
// Seleccionamos los datos para crear los marcadores en el Mapa de Google //serian direccion, lat y lng 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '["' . $row['direccion'] . '", ' . $row['lat'] . ', ' . $row['lng'] . '],';}
?>
```

app.php

```
<?php
// Archivo de Conexión a la Base de Datos 
include('conexion.php');
// Listamos las direcciones con todos sus datos (lat, lng, dirección, etc.)
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM google_maps_php_mysql");
// Creamos una tabla para listar los datos 
echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
echo "<table class='table'>
<thead class='thead-dark'>
<tr>
<th scope='col'>Nombre</th>
<th scope='col'>Dirección</th>
<th scope='col'>Latitud</th>
<th scope='col'>Longitud</th>
<th scope='col'>País</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td scope='col'>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";
echo "<td scope='col'>" . $row['direccion'] . "</td>";
echo "<td scope='col'>" . $row['lat'] . "</td>";
echo "<td scope='col'>" . $row['lng'] . "</td>";
echo "<td scope='col'>" . $row['pais'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">
#mapa {
height: 50vh;
}
.h2s {
font-size: 3vh;
}
</style>          
</head>
<body> 
<header>
</header>
<div class="pccp mt-5 mb-3" align="center">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 </script>
</div>
<main role="main">
<div class="container text-center mt-5">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<!-- Contenedor del Mapa de Google --> 
<div id="mapa"></div>               
</div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h2 class="h2s">Direcciónes en la Base de Datos MySQL</h2>
<!-- Archivo PHP con la lógica para mostrar una tabla con las ubicaciones -->
<?php include('php/app.php'); ?> 
</div>
</div>  
<hr>
</div>
</main>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
mapOptions
});
map.setTilt(50);
// Crear múltiples marcadores desde la Base de Datos 
var marcadores = [
<?php include('php/marcadores.php'); ?>
];
// Creamos la ventana de información para cada Marcador
var ventanaInfo = [
<?php include('php/info_marcadores.php'); ?>
];
// Creamos la ventana de información con los marcadores 
var mostrarMarcadores = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
marcadores, i;
// Colocamos los marcadores en el Mapa de Google 
for (i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(marcadores[i][1], marcadores[i][2]);
bounds.extend(position);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: position,
map: map,
title: marcadores[i][0]
});
// Colocamos la ventana de información a cada Marcador del Mapa de Google 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
return function() {
mostrarMarcadores.setContent(ventanaInfo[i][0]);
mostrarMarcadores.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker, i));
// Centramos el Mapa de Google para que todos los marcadores se puedan ver 
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
// Aplicamos el evento 'bounds_changed' que detecta cambios en la //ventana del Mapa de Google, también le configramos un zoom de 14 
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
this.setZoom(14);
google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});
}
// Lanzamos la función 'initMap' para que muestre el Mapa con Los //Marcadores y toda la configuración realizada 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo recibiendo un valor atravez de GET ejemplo:

```
if(isset($_GET['pais'])){
  $pais = filter_var($_GET['pais'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM google_maps_php_mysql where pais = {$pais}");
}

if(isset($_GET['direccion'])){
  $direccion= filter_var($_GET['direccion'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM google_maps_php_mysql where direccion= {$direccion}");
}

if($result->num_rows > 0){
// resto del codigo
```

ahora solo vastaria con agregar a tu url

```
http://localhost/proyecto/index.php?pais=usa
http://localhost/proyecto/index.php?direccion=miami
```

Comment: Hola Bryro, gracias po rla respuesta. Con este código, ¿tendría que tener un formulario para i rpasando los diferentes filtros?